# Randomize the data in a multidimensional array (second tier)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [site1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data

                )

    [site2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data
                    [1] => data
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => data
                )
         )
)
```

I am trying to randomize the data for each site ([site1], [site2]) but don't mix the data between sites. So it would be like a second tire randomization.

For example, after the randomization, the position [0] for [site1] would have different data, maybe the data from the earlier position [3].

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($sites as $i => $site) {
   shuffle($sites[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You *map* the [`shuffle` function](http://php.net/shuffle) to the array:

```
$shuffle = function($array) {
    $r = shuffle($array);
    return $array;
};

$sites = array_map($shuffle, $sites);
```

Or:

```
foreach ($sites as &$site) shuffle($site);
unset($site);
```

Comment: This looks classy but it does not work; maybe I can give you a link to my site and a print_r to take a look at the actual array? The site has light adult content so I hope you won't mind.

Comment: Well you could also just tell what does not work in your case ;)

Comment: After I apply the above function I get: Array
(
    [site1] => 1
    [site2] => 1
    [site3] => 1
)  All the data for each site has gone.

Comment: This is because `shuffle` returning either `true` or `false` and not the "randomized" array. So `array_map` will use the return value of `shuffle` as the value.

Comment: Ty clenfort, any ideas on what to do?

Comment: @webmasters: I edited the answer, totally right, an oversight of me, clentfort's `foreach` example was obviously his/her idea, you find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12556487/367456

Comment: I am going to go with clentforts, it worked and he answered firt. Hope you don't mind. Ty very much; also I have upped your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another, (not as good as shuffle) way ;-)

```
foreach ($site as $key => $data) {
  $values = array();
  $rand   = array_rand($data, count($data));
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($rand); $i++)) {
    $values[] = $site[$key][$rand[$i]];  
  }
  $site[$key] = $values;
}
```